# How to display LaTeX symbols in Flextable (R)

Tags: r, flextable

I have generated the following table using the `Flextable` package in R. I created a conditionally formatted column with LaTeX arrow symbols in it, however the symbols aren't displayed when I generate it as a flextable. Is there a way to fix this?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)

data.frame(one = c(10,20,30), two = c(30,20,6)) %>% 
  mutate(Trend = case_when(.[,2] == .[,1] ~ "$\\rightarrow$", .[,2] > .[,1] ~ "$\\nearrow$", TRUE ~ "$\\searrow$")) %>% 
  flextable()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be easier to do this with unicode values for the symbols

```
library(dplyr)
library(flextable)
data.frame(one = c(10,20,30), two = c(30,20,6)) %>% 
  mutate(Trend = ifelse(two == one,  "\U2192", "\U2190")) %>% 
  flextable()
```

-output

[image]